# What exactly is a connection in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to databases, have done my basic "homework" regarding the theoretical part, and set about using MySQL Server through MySQL Workbench.

I have created four "connections" which appear on the Workbench homescreen dashboard, and I have also created some tables. But when I login through any connection (using user name and password), I can see all of the tables that I have created. So can anyone please tell me what is the point behind multiple connections then? What exactly is a "Connection" in MySQL Workbench?

I tried googling it, searched it on StackOverflow, and even referred the user manual of MySQL workbench, but got no answers.

Comment: It is a user connecting to a server that may or not have a referenced database yet for that connection. That user can have many. Think many users, not just you out there wants data

Comment: @DrewPierce If so, then how can one connection view the tables that were created through other connections? Won't one user be able to see what others have created?

Comment: That's the point most of the time. Other times no, you grant rights

Comment: @DrewPierce Seems like you have explained the essence of it. Thank you.

Comment: Check out create user and grant commands for mysql. It will make sense

Answer (score 5):

Each MySQL connection contains its own set of definitions. For example, the connections might connect to different MySQL servers, or the same MySQL server with different usernames, or enable SSL for one, or you might set up a connection to a remote MySQL server using the SSH options, and so on.

As for multiple connections to the same local MySQL server, you might have one connection using "root" with another using a less privileged user. Depending on how you set up the users, they may (or may not) both have rights to see and use the same databases (information).

So to summarize, connections simply connect to the MySQL server. If two connections use the same exact information then the results will be identical. However, that is not a common use case.